# Create an array of rows VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

New to VBA. I'm trying to create an array of rows.

Basically, I have an entire sheet and want to take all the rows that start with a certain value ("MA") in column 8.

I eventually want to manipulate that array (as if it were a range), and paste it somewhere else in the sheet. Can anyone help? Here's my code so far:

```
Dim top0M As Variant
ReDim top0M(1 To 1) As Variant

For i = 4 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 8).Value Like "MA*" Then
        top0M(UBound(top0M)) = Rows(i)
        ReDim Preserve top0M(1 To UBound(top0M) + 1) As Variant
    End If
Next i
```

This code runs but I'm not sure how to debug it to know if I even have the right rows inside. Can I paste these rows as if they were a range?

Comment: You are creating an array of arrays, so to save to another sheet you will need to loop and assign each array to the next open row in your target sheet.

Comment: To build an array of ranges you would need `Dim top0M As Variant` and `ReDim top0M(1 To 1) As Variant` change to `Dim top0M As Range` and `ReDim top0M(1 To 1) As Range` although you really only need one `Dim top0M(1 To 1) As Range`

Comment: is there a row that we can use to limit the scope of column?  You are looping the whole sheet 1048576 rows and getting all the columns most which will be blank and we should ignore.

Comment: @Kyle It doesn't work with Range, keeps giving me the 'expected array' elsewhere

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, I replaced it with UsedRange.Rows.Count. No wonder it was so slow!

Comment: @ScottCraner How do I then paste each inner array as a row in a sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sets the range and loads the whole into an array then it loads a different array with the lines that you want:

```
With ActiveSheet 'This should be changed to the name of the worksheet: Worksheets("MySheet")
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))


    Dim tot As Variant
    tot = rng.Value

    Dim top0M As Variant
    ReDim top0M(1 To Application.CountIf(.Range("H:H"), "MA*"), 1 To UBound(tot, 2)) As Variant
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(tot, 1) To UBound(tot, 1)
        If tot(i, 8) Like "MA*" Then
            Dim j As Long
            For j = LBound(tot, 2) To UBound(tot, 2)
                top0M(k, j) = tot(i, j)
            Next j
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

'to print to a sheet just assign the values:

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(top0M, 1), UBound(top0M, 2)).Value = top0M
```

Comment: I get an 'object required' runtime exception at line:
`Set rng = .Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Value`

Comment: @Tiberiu I would expect a marked increase in speed over your old code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim x           As Variant

x = ActiveSheet.Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Value
x = FilterArray(x, 8, "MA*", True)

ActiveSheet.Range("K14").Resize(UBound(x, 1), UBound(x, 2)).Value = x
End Sub

Function FilterArray(ByVal myRefArr As Variant, ByVal col As Integer, ByVal refValue As String, ByVal equal As Boolean) As Variant
Dim a           As Variant
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long
Dim n           As Long

On Error Resume Next
    n = 1

    If refValue = "" Then
        FilterArray = myRefArr
    Else
        ReDim a(1 To UBound(myRefArr, 1), 1 To UBound(myRefArr, 2))
        For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            If IIf(equal, UCase(myRefArr(i, col)) Like UCase(refValue), Not (UCase(myRefArr(i, col)) Like UCase(refValue))) Then
                For j = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                    a(n, j) = myRefArr(i, j)
                Next j
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next i

        a = Application.Transpose(a)
        ReDim Preserve a(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To n - 1)
        a = Application.Transpose(a)
        FilterArray = a
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```